# Azure App Service Environment - New-AzureRmWebApp broken?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have been developing deployment scripts to create and automate Azure Web Apps and those are working well.

Today I am trying to move these into an App Service Environment in preparation for production.

I find out that the command used for creating Web Apps doesn't work with an ASE.

```
New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $SiteName -Location $location -AppServicePlan $AppServicePlan
New-AzureRmWebApp : Server farm with name ASE01 not found.
```

However when I view in Azure Resource Explorer I can see that the 'Server Farm' is there, along with the normal Web App Service Plans.

```
Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/ASE01
```

It's extremely frustrating to spend weeks developing scripts to automate stuff and then find that the App Service Plan simply does not interface with these scripts.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

James,

To create WebApps in ASE you need to use the following command

```
New-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName WebAppResourceGroup -Name webappname -Location "North Central US" -AppServicePlan WebApp-AppServicePlan -ASEName ASEName -ASEResourceGroupName ASEResourceGroupName
```

Note that the location parameter is required though not used - just need to be a valid Azure location.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I wish I could give you a hundred votes! I added the code and now my script is working to create the web apps!

Comment: @James could you please mark this as the answer since issue is solved? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidEbbo Thanks for reminding me, I'm new to stack so I completely missed that!